# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder to encode my password but when i use its encode function to encode the password in my save function in UserService class it gives me this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceInter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'crypt'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

When i remove this it works but the password is not encoded.

UserService class:

```
   @Service
   public class UserService implements UserServiceInterface{

@Autowired
UserRepository repo;

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder crypt;

@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepo;

public void save(User user) {


        user.setPassword(crypt.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Role role = roleRepo.findByRole("USER");
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(role)));
        repo.save(user);


   }

@Override
public User findByUsername(String userName) {

    User user = repo.findByUserName(userName);
    return user;

}

    }
```

UserServiceInterface:

```
   @Service
    public interface UserServiceInterface {


public void save(User user);

public User findByUsername(String userName);

    }
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends 
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserPrincipleDetailsService user;

@Autowired
private SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
    Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());


}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()

        .antMatchers("/assets/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/registerUser").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
        .successHandler(successHandler)
        .loginPage("/home").permitAll()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/signin")
        .failureUrl("/home?error=true")


        .and()
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new 
    AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/home");

}

@Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {

    DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new 
    DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    dao.setUserDetailsService(user);

    return dao;


}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change

```
@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder crypt;
```

to

```
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder crypt
```

or change passwordEncoder method

```
@Bean
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: @JonathanJohx because BCryptPasswordEncoder  is class and spring will try locate object of same class or any matching subclass, however PasswordEncoder is an interface if it is declared , spring will look implementing class,

Comment: @Shailesh thanx a lot man. i changed it to PasswordEncoder and it worked.

Comment: @ShaileshChandra why cant I just Autowired PasswordEncoder crypt?

Comment: Because PasswordEncoser is an Interface and it has at least 10 implementation and then you need to tell which bean to wire

Answer (score 5):

I agree Shailesh answer is 100% acceptable. If you wants to know

### meaning of "No qualifying bean of type"

From below code

```java
@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

**Definitely bean is created** with the **name** `passwordEncoder` of **type** `PasswordEncoder`.

But

```java
@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder crypt;
```

Above code asking spring container to inject a bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.
(Note: passwordEncoder bean may be instance of BCryptPasswordEncoder but bean is of type `PasswordEncoder` and hence there is no bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder`)

> *Hence exception* 
>  
>   **No qualifying bean of type** 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.**BCryptPasswordEncoder**' **available**

1. Hence you can autowire bean of name `passwordEncoder` to a field of type `PasswordEncoder`.

```java
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder crypt;
```

2. Also you can get bean by name `passwordEncoder` from application context

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

inYourMethod()
{
   PasswordEncoder crypt = context.getBean("passwordEncoder");
}
```

---

### For Quick understanding of `@Bean`, `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` Simple 6 cases that explains very well

**Case 1: Created bean type and Autowired field's type are Different - [This Will not work]**
(No qualifying bean of type BCryptPasswordEncoder available)

```java
@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

**Case 2: Created bean type and Autowired field's type are same - [This Will not work]**

```java
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

**Case 3: Autowired field's type is super type of created bean - [This will work]**
Is bean created is of type BCryptPasswordEncoder - Yes
Is bean created is of type PasswordEncoder - Yes

```java
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

**Case 4: Multiple beans of same type and without @Qualifier - [This will not work]**

> NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'o.s.s.c.p.PasswordEncoder' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: bcryptPasswordEncoder,md4PasswordEncoder

```java
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder bcrypt;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder md4;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder md4PasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new Md4PasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

**Case 5: Multiple beans of same type and with @Qualifier - [This will work]**
Qualifier helps in selecting bean for injection

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bcryptPasswordEncoder")
PasswordEncoder bcrypt;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("md4PasswordEncoder")
PasswordEncoder md4;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder md4PasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new Md4PasswordEncoder();
}
```

---

**Case 6: Multiple beans of same type and without @Qualifier but field name same as bean name - [This will work]**

Here Field name acts as qualifier and helps when there are multiple beans of same type.

```java
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder md4PasswordEncoder;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder md4PasswordEncoder() 
{
    return new Md4PasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation and detailed answer , It will help others. probably you want to edit answer and add case 7 , if one has Multiple beans of same type , then one can also mark a bean as primary using @Primary  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary

Comment: @Shailesh In fact you are fast, I was writing answer. But saw your answer. :) I descarded my answer. But after seeing JonathanJohx comment, I supposed to write detailed answer.

Comment: haha never mind, happens with me too, ,anyways  we wanted to solve the problem and we did :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your applicationContext.xml for developper working with xml.

```
<bean id="bcrypt" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"></bean>
```